# "Он мне если не друг, то хороший знакомый". Знаки препинания

Tags: пунктуация

**Он мне если не друг, то хороший знакомый.**

Нужны ли другие знаки препинания в этом предложении?

Answer (score 2):

**Он мне если не друг, то хороший знакомый.**

**ЕСЛИ (И) НЕ... ТО, союз**
Соединяет однородные члены предложения, первый из которых содержит нереальное условие, а второй – предположение, допущение. Запятая ставится перед второй частью союза (перед словом «то»).

http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_185